# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `Todo` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: json-deserialization, rest-assured, pojo

I have this json which I converted to a POJO

The JSON converted to POJO file

```
[
    {
        "postId": 81,
        "id": 401,
        "name": "cum voluptate sint voluptas veritatis",
        "email": "Vella.Mayer@colten.net",
        "body": "sit delectus recusandae qui\net cupiditate sed ipsum culpa et fugiat ab\nillo dignissimos quo est repellat dolorum neque\nvoluptates sed sapiente ab aut rerum enim sint voluptatum"
    },
    {
        "postId": 81,
        "id": 403,
        "name": "cum voluptate sint voluptas veritatis",
        "email": "Vella.Mayer@colten.net",
        "body": "sit delectus recusandae qui\net cupiditate sed ipsum culpa et fugiat ab\nillo dignissimos quo est repellat dolorum neque\nvoluptates sed sapiente ab aut rerum enim sint voluptatum"
    }
]
```

This is the POJO class I converted it into

```
public class TodoItem{
    private int id;
    private boolean completed;
    private String title;
    private int userId;
```

I tried using todo to validate the response that it of the type of the class but always get this error.

```
Todo todo = response.getBody().as(Todo.class);
Assert.assertTrue(response.statusCode() == 200);
```

Error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `io.christdoes.pojo.todo.Todo` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things you did wrong:

- The POJO that you're matching
- The way you map (Array cannot map to one single object)

It would be

```
List<TodoItem> todoItems = response.as(new TypeRef<>() {});
```

POJO (I use lombok to generate getters/setters)

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TodoItem{
    private int postId;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String body;
}
```